# Printing Fields Multiple Times

Tags: 7, theming, entities

I have a custom template for a node (Photograph) that needs to print a field multiple times for different reasons. You can see an example here: http://history.arvadahistory.org/photograph/elizabeth-lunau-house-52st-and-dover

Where you see in the table "Individual ID", there is supposed to be a field printout, but I had to cut it out so a copy of the field could be printed with priority.

So using the above example, the Individual ID should be printed HF513, but I can't for unknown reasons, place this field in multiple places, and I need it absolutely attached to the "Order Image" button, where the link it loads for the above example is as such: http://history.arvadahistory.org/order-historic-image?edit[attributes][2]=HF513

Below is the code I have included in my template, as you can see, the second row, where the initial copy of "Individual ID" is supposed to be printed, I have commented out because if I leave it uncommented, it won't print the field the second time near the bottom with the "Order Image" button.

As a note, I do have a module that provides my fields with a "Do not write drupal standard markup around the field" option so I can print out the individual ID with just the ID to include in my "Order Image" URL.

```
<table width="100%" border="0">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td class="category">Object ID</td>
        <td class="non-title"><?php print render ($content['field_photo_object_id']);?></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="category">Individual ID</td>
        <td class="non-title"><?php /**print render ($content['field_individual_id']);**/?></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="category">Object Name</td>
        <td class="non-title"><?php print render ($content['field_object_name']);?></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="category">Description</td>
        <td class="non-title"><?php print render ($content['body']);?></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="category">Copyright</td>
        <td class="non-title"><?php print render ($content['field_copyright']);?></td>
      </tr>
       <tr>
         <td class="category">Properties &amp; Locations</td>
         <td class="non-title"><?php print render ($content['field_property_references']);?></td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
         <td class="category">People</td>
         <td class="non-title"><?php print render ($content['field_biography_references']);?></td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
        <td class="category">Photograph Category</td>
        <td class="non-title"><?php print render ($content['field_photograph_category']);?></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="category">Collection</td>
        <td class="non-title"><?php print render ($content['field_ahsphotograph_collection']);?></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="category">Photograph Date(s)</td>
        <td class="non-title"><?php print render ($content['field_photograph_date_s_']);?><?php print render ($content['field_date_specific_']);?></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="category">Original Available</td>
        <td class="non-title"><?php print render ($content['field_original_available']);?></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="category">Print Available</td>
        <td class="non-title"><?php print render ($content['field_print_available']);?></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="category">Negative Available</td>
        <td class="non-title"><?php print render ($content['field_negative_available']);?></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="category">Credit Line</td>
        <td class="non-title"><?php print render ($content['field_credit_line']);?></td>
      </tr>
       <tr>
        <td class="category">Tags</td>
        <td class="non-title"><?php print render ($content['field_photograph_tags']);?></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><?php print render ($content['field_photo_object_id']);?><?php print render($content['field_photo_object_id']['1'][0]['value']); ?></td>
      <td><a href="http://history.arvadahistory.org/order-historic-image?edit[attributes][2]=<?php print render ($content['field_individual_id']);?>" target="_blank""><img src="http://history.arvadahistory.org/sites/default/files/imageorder_small.gif"></a><img src="http://history.arvadahistory.org/sites/default/files/feedback_small.gif" style="padding-left:50px"></td></tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

--------------------------------------UPDATE--------------
As per the suggestion @rovr138 I have implemented the "tmpField" suggestion, which has worked out. I'll accept his answer tonight if there is nothing else that pops up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick fix (since this is live), above table add,

```
<?php
  $tmpField = $content['field_individual_id'];
?>
```

Then the commented field, change it to:

```
    <td class="category">Individual ID</td>
    <td class="non-title"><?php print render ($tmpField); ?></td>
```

Comment: Thanks! That worked. Like I said in my above update, if I don't see anything else I'll just use yours as the example since it worked well.